# Limiting output from reducer in Map reduce API

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop2, reduce

In my mapreduce program, output of my reducer produces 1 Million lines of output, but i just need initial first 3 output lines. And for that i am maintaining an instance variable in my Reducer class that counts how many records it has seen, and stops emitting them after 3. But still reducers has to go thru all the 1 Million records. Is there a way i can stop the execution as soon as it reads first 3 records to improve the performance of my code .

And also here i have to make the reducer count as 1 , so that my instance variable count will work properly, and that is also adding up to reduce the performance of the program.

Thanks, I will really appreciate your help.

Comment: I never thought of this scenario, really, good question :)

Answer (score 0):

In your case you can set the number of reducers to 1, inside this class you can count the first 3 lines and emit output for them, then ignore any other input emitting nothing. This does not stop the framework to keep calling the reduce() method for all the keys which have been computed by the mapper.

If it is possible you should reduce the output at mapper level, combiner or partitioner.

AFAIK there is not way for the reduce to stop the process.

Comment: I did the same thing.. was just looking for some more optimized way to improve the performance of my reducer code..also i cannot limit the output data from the Map side in my situation.

Comment: You are trying to stop the reducer, you should provide less data to it. To boost performance you should start thinking about Spark.